# Android app launch from url scheme is very slow

Tags: android, xamarin, url-scheme

I have a Xamarin project in which the app can be optionally launched via a URL scheme from another app. On Android, when I launch the app by tapping the icon, the launch screen appears for about 5 seconds then the app appears, but when I launch from another app via URL, the launch screen sits for 25-30 seconds before the app runs. I don't see a similar problem on the iOS version.

I'm using the method and code provided in the Android docs to open the app via URL.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem?

Comment: What have you done to debug this? If you add some logging to the app you may be able to narrow down where the issue is.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure what I would log. The app hasn't launched yet; it won't produce a log.

Comment: Do you do some operation in Android?

Comment: I did this: I capture a DateTime value at the very beginning of my App instance constructor and again inside the OnAppear method of the first activity to appear. The time difference is only 800ms. The huge delay is occurring somewhere between the intent request from the calling app and the launching of the second app, but I don't know how to investigate that.

Comment: We could not make sure what cause more time. You could refer to the link below to speed up Android app startup time.https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/launch-time